# CakePHP 3 override default route

Tags: overriding, router, cakephp-3.0

Since `Router::promote();` has been removed in CakePHP 3, what should one be using to override routes set in Config/routes.php from a plugin?

Say that i would want to overwrite

`$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);`

With

`$routes->connect('/', ['plugin' => 'Plugin','controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'displayInPlugin']);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution was to simply put `Plugin::routes();` over the default routes...d'oh.

```
Plugin::routes();
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {   
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```